# Conditional compilation based on GHC point release

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, conditional-compilation

I need to work around a [bug](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9148) present in (I think) GHC (7.8.0 - 7.8.2). I don't think I can use `__GLASGOW_HASKELL__` since we only get major and minor version numbers, and I don't *think* I can use the `base` library version (although I can't find a list associating ghc releases -> `base` versions).

In other words I need to do:

```
#if GHC < 7.8.3
    this code
#else
    this code
#endif
```

Comment: This will probably seem very hacky, but you could use a cabal preConf hook which runs `ghc --version` and passes the appropriate CPP arg to the build stage.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Actually, it looks like base 4.7.0.1 shipped with GHC 7.8.3, so I think maybe hopefully I can use that to set a CPP flag. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I somehow missed this in the [docs](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#configurations), but this is easily done with `impl()`

```
library foo
    ...
    if impl(ghc >= 7.8.3)
       cpp-options: -DTRYREADMVAR
```